# What does "caravan a house" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've come across the phrase in the second episode of *Modern Family*. Here is the context;

> I'm a real-estate mogul. What?! No, I am a real-estate agent. Um, we **caravanned that house**. Great, uh, deck.

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/caravan-that-house.2261224/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In [US] real estate a caravan refers to a showing method that some listing
> agents will use when selling a home. A caravan involves inviting real
> estate agents into a home, or more often a series of homes, listed for
> sale in hopes to achieve higher visibility and marketing. The sales
> theory behind a caravan is that other agents know what their buyers
> are looking for or may know of an interested buyer that might
> otherwise have missed the property.

The noun can be made into a verb also.

[In Real Estate, what is a Caravan?](https://www.infobloom.com/in-real-estate-what-is-a-caravan.htm)

The meaning of 'caravan' here is probably derived from the historical term meaning a group of people [travelling together for protection, e.g. in a desert], and not the (outside US) meaning of 'small mobile home towed behind a motor vehicle'.